# Objective C - Make a UIImageView jump

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiimageview

I have been stuck trying to make my character jump, and have tried both hardcoding the y position of the character and using uiimageview animations. What is the best way to do it and the best example of code (because I think I have done the two previous examples wrong) - as I am quite new.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is sample code using blocks(triggered on button action).

```
- (IBAction)btnClicked:(id)sender {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f animations:^{
        CGRect currentRect=self.imgView.frame;
        currentRect.origin.y-=30;

        [self.imgView setFrame:currentRect];

    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

       [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f animations:^{
          CGRect currentRect=self.imgView.frame;

          currentRect.origin.y+=30;

          [self.imgView setFrame:currentRect];

      }];
    }];
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! works nicely, however, I have added similar code so it travels along the x axis too, my only problem is it doesn't jump in a curve shape.

I know this is because of the y axis being incremented with the same value each time, is there a way to increment in a number which slowly grows - or - is there a better way to animate in an arc shape?

Comment: you can define the path you want the jump to be performed along. it's done using CoreAnimation, check http://nachbaur.com/blog/core-animation-part-4 . Also, on WWDC 2010 there were some nice examples showing movement along the path

Comment: Would you be able to provide example code yourself? Like i said I'm knew and the videos/tutorial are hard to follow or understand

Comment: how can i make this animation thing for indefinite time ?